# How do I fill a matrix with 0 in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to fill an 8x8 matrix just with 0.

I know it is possible to do the following:

```
board = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        )
```

This time is just an 8x8 so it's not too much work, but what if I have an 200x200 matrix, what should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val board = Array(8) { IntArray(8) { 0 } }
```